# How to map ktor response to object depending on response status code

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Let's consider I do a simple request:

```
get("/getUser/$userId")
```

The result may be performed successfully and return `String` with `status=200` or may complete with an exception and return `status=400` and error object:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Something went wrong!"
}
```

I want to map all responses to a common object:

```
data class Response<T>(
  val success: Boolean,
  val result: T,
  val error: Map<String, String>
)
```

Is there any possible solution to map success and not success results into one common object?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept on the `Transform` phase of the `HttpResponsePipeline` to be able transforming any response to the `Response` type:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*

suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        expectSuccess = false
    }

    client.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) { (info, body) ->
        val response = when (context.response.status) {
            HttpStatusCode.OK -> Response(success = true, result = body, error = emptyMap())
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest -> Response(success = false, result = body, error = mapOf("error" to "Some error"))
            else -> error("Cannot map status code ${context.response.status}")
        }

        proceedWith(HttpResponseContainer(info, response))
    }

    val r = client.get<Response<Any>>("https://httpbin.org/status/400")
    println(r.success)
}
```